# Checking if list been sorted in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing sorting algorithms in Prolog and need to see if the algorithm is working correctly. So I need to see before and after what a list looks like. For instance consider permutation sort

```
permutation_sort(L,S) :- permutation(L,S), sorted(S).


sorted([]).
sorted([_]).
sorted([X,Y|ZS]) :- X =< Y, sorted([Y|ZS]).

permutation([],[]).
permutation([X|XS],YS) :- permutation(XS,ZS), select(X,YS,ZS).
```

Since the output I get when I try `permutation_sort([3,2,1,4],s)` is the word `false`, I don't know if the list is sorted/algorithm worked correctly.

How would I be able to see the output of s at the end?

Comment: The code produces sorted results, but your query is incorrect, you here ask if the `permutation_sort/2` of `[3,2,1,4]` is `s`, but `s` is a constant, not a list, and definitely not a sorted list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, ah I see. So I just had to change it to a capital.